# probability of having three cards from 24 in a hand.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $24$ cards were distributed to $3$ persons ($8$ cards each). From those $24$, there are exactly $3$ diamonds.

What is the probability that a person gets these $3$ diamonds?

Comment: Are you familiar with the hypergeometric distribution ?

Comment: $\frac {\binom{3}{1} \cdot \binom{21}{5} \cdot \binom{16}{8} \cdot \binom{8}{8}} {\binom{24}{8} \cdot \binom{16}{8} \cdot \binom{8}{8}}\approx8.3\%$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that a given person gets three diamonds is

$$
\frac{\binom{21}5}{\binom{24}8}=\frac{8\cdot7\cdot6}{24\cdot23\cdot22}\;.
$$

You can see this either from the fact that that person can only choose $5$ out of the $21$ non-diamond cards instead of choosing $8$ out of all $24$ cards, or by first distributing the three diamonds, with probabilities of $\frac8{24}$, $\frac7{23}$ and $\frac6{22}$ of giving them to that person.

Since at most one person can get all three diamonds, the probability that any person gets three diamonds is three times that value.